# How to replace with jquery a character that can vary in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

Basically I have a url that needs to be changed dinamically to call on another functions, so for example I have "index/buscasimples/finalidade/1/filtro/1/", and when a specific button is pressed, I need to replace the part where it is "filtro/1/" for another one. The problem is that this number "/1/" can vary, from 1 to 3, so I'll probably need an if to do the work. But I want to know if there is another way that could help me...

To be clearer, the code is like this

```
  $('#filtro').change(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var filtro = $('#filtro option:selected').val();
    var urlAtual = window.location.href; 
    var url = urlAtual.replace('/buscasimples/','/buscafiltrada/');
    url += 'filtro/'+filtro+'/';
    window.location = url;
})
```

This function changes the url and put on the "filtro" that is needed, and work fine for the first time. But then when the proccess is repeated, there'll be 2 "filtro" in the url, so I want to replace the "filtro" and the number that is next to it, but this number can be 1, 2 or 3 as I said. There's some native jquery function that can replace one character whatever they are like "replace.('filtro/@/')" or something?  Sorry for long question, I got that application already made and I'm trying to deal with it haha Thanks!!

Comment: Where's the option html code ?

Comment: `                <select name="filtro" id="filtro" class="sel-custom form-control">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Escolha um filtro</option>
                    <option value="1">Nenhum</option>
                    <option value="2">Maior preço</option>
                    <option value="3">Menor preço</option>
                </select>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `indexOf()` .. try this code and read the comments in the code please

```
$('#filtro').change(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var filtro = $('#filtro option:selected').val();
    var urlAtual = window.location.href; 
    var url = urlAtual.replace('/buscasimples/','/buscafiltrada/');
    // <<<<<<<<< the new code start 
    if(url.indexOf('filtro/') > -1){  // if filtro/ found in the url'
       urlSplit = url.split('filtro/'); // split url to get the url before 'filtro/'
       url = urlsplit[0]+'filtro/'+filtro+'/'; // append new filtro to the first url string
    }else{  // if url doesn't have filtro then append to url
       url += 'filtro/'+filtro+'/'; 
    }
    // <<<<<<<<<<< end of new code
    window.location = url;
})
```

Comment: Man that was genius work! I'm really glad to find people who spend time like this to help others, you really made my day better! All the best, thankss!

Comment: @op_exchanger l'm really glad to make your day better.. and hope all your days comes better and better .. keep awesome and enjoy coding ... good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current url already contains `filtro/number`, is so, we `replace` it with the **new** filtro number, otherwise, we add `filtro/numero` to the `url` and `redirect`.

You can use something like:

```
$('#filtro').change(function(e) { 
var filtro = $('#filtro option:selected').val();
var urlAtual = window.location.href; 
var url = urlAtual.replace('/buscasimples/','/buscafiltrada/');
if (/filtro\/\d+/i.test(url)) {
    url = url.replace(/filtro\/\d+/i, "filtro/"+filtro);
}else{
    url += 'filtro/'+filtro+'/';
}
window.location = url;
})
```